# How to make iptables not SNAT locally generated packets

Tags: iptables, nat

Most SNAT examples give following

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 100.200.100.200
```

but, it appears that this apply not only to forwarded packets but also to packets coming from localhost. This is unwanted. Outgoing packets from localhost may be something important (SMTP, etc), I don't want to change it's IP to one used for NAT.

I saw examples with

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 100.200.100.200
```

but this seems to be unreliable to me as it is one more place that you need to keep an eye on when you want change something. Is there a way to define that outgoing packets from localhost should not be SNAT'ed no matter what?

Comment: How have you verified that the source IP of those packets coming from localhost have that address? POSTROUTING chain only applies to packets that are routed via the machine. OUTPUT chain applies to locally generated packets, and therefore I find your issue quite odd.

Comment: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o lo -j LOG --log-prefix "test: "
   nat.POSTROUTING applies to all packets, check iptables diagram

Answer (score 3):

If you look at iptables diagram
(choose any https://gist.github.com/nerdalert/a1687ae4da1cc44a437d)
you can see that nat.POSTROUTING is applied not only for forwarded packets but also for outgoing packets from this host. So, if you have 2 IP's (100.100.100.5 and 100.100.100.6) assigned to this host and have something like this in your iptables

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 100.100.100.5
```

all connections from this host outgoing to **eth0** will be changed by SNAT. Even when software binds to certain IP. Thats could be bad.

This can be easily avoided by adding above previous setting

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL -j ACCEPT
```

this will accept any packet generated by this host, without SNAT, works for all IP's that are assigned to this host - 127.0.0.1 or 100.100.100.5 or 100.100.100.6 (secondary ip), etc

Comment: How we can test to verify this is happend??